# Django 1.9 can not find newapp

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

I have worked with django 1.7 and recently started new project with django 1.9. The major difference with starting a new app was that new app is created with apps.py file. I read on [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/) that now you have to use

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'newapp.apps.NewAppConfig',
    ...
]
```

(old was just `'newapp'`)

In my new project i have all my apps in a new directory called 'myapps'.
But if i use 
`'myapps.newapp.apps.NewAppConfig'`
than django gives error `ImportError: No module named newapp`
But if i use the old way i.e.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapps.newapp',
    ...
]
```

Than it works perfectly without error but configs in apps.py file may not be applied ( i don't know how it works ).

So which is the right way to put newapp in INSTALLED_APPS settings for django 1.9 when you got all your new apps in another directory like "myapps" with apps.py config file also working?

Comment: You don't "have to" use it. The old method `'myapps.newapp'` is equally valid. Only use the longer version if you need to run stuff in `apps.py`

Comment: @C14L yes i understand that you don't have to but that is my question that what if i need to use apps.py in future and i just can't use that feature because of my directory structure.

Comment: Does your `newapp` directory contain `__init__.py`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes newapp do have __init__.py and urls include in main url directory is also working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your apps directory is in the `myapps` directory, then check the following:

1. Your `myapps` directory should have an `__init__.py`
2. Include `myapps` in the path when you include the app in `INSTALLED_APPS`, i.e. `'myapps.newapp.apps.NewAppConfig',`
3. Include `myapps` in the app config's [`name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name) attribute:

   ```
   class NewAppConfig(AppConfig):
       name = 'myapps.newapp'
   ```

Comment: Thanks man. I was missing the third point... I had name = 'newapp' in apps.py and that was causing all the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is inside the "myapps" directory, you still need to include that in the path: `"myapps.newapp.apps.NewAppConfig"`.

Comment: As i stated in the question using "myapps.newapp.apps.NewAppConfig" gives ImportError: No module named newapp